# How to get SVG child element position relative to SVG position on page, D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a circle pin on a SVG map. Where the SVG is inside a div "location-map" with overflow:hidden. The SVG dimension is larger than the div dimension.

```
<div class="location-map">
    <svg></svg>
</div>

svg.selectAll(".pin")
    .data(places)
    .enter().append("circle", ".pin")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("fill", "#fff")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + projection([
            d.location.longitude,
            d.location.latitude
            ]) + ")";
});
```

I would like to get the circle pin position on SVG so that I can reposition the SVG within the div with negative margin to make the circle pin display horizontally and vertically center on the div.

How do I get the x, y position of the circle pin?

Answer (score 0):

[SVGCircle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle) has `cx` and `cy` attributes, standing for centerX and centerY.
d3's `.attr()` method also allows to get those.

```js
var circle = d3.selectAll(".pin");
var x = circle.attr('cx');
var y = circle.attr('cy');

snippet.log('x: '+x);
snippet.log('y: '+y)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<div class="location-map">
  <svg>
    <circle class="pin" cx="50" cy="50" r="25"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: With this I get this error

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null_a.attr @ d3.min.js:3(anonymous function)".

I am using this ver.
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js

Comment: Hmm you're not getting the circle, try to do `d3.selectAll('.pin').append('circle', '.pin').select('circle').attr()`